# Java prepared statement with mysql giving error

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to run a jdbc query. Here is my code

```
 Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(svnLog.getTime().getTime());

 String query = "Insert into transaction (RevisionId, AuthorId, LogMessage, Time) values (?,?,?,?) ";


    System.out.println("The query is " + query + svnLog.getRevisionId() + "," + svnLog.getAuthorId() + "," + svnLog.getLogMessage() + "," + timeStamp);

    try {

        PreparedStatement stmt = connManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setLong(1, svnLog.getRevisionId());
        stmt.setString(2, svnLog.getAuthorId());
        stmt.setString(3, svnLog.getLogMessage());
        stmt.setTimestamp(4, timeStamp);

        System.out.println("After binding " + stmt.toString());
```

This throws following exception.

```
   After binding com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement@478e4327: Insert into transaction   (RevisionId, AuthorId, LogMessage, Time) values (214,'mknauer','Initial import.','2007-03-01 06:39:21.128') 
   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?)' at line 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1402)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1317)
at dataminer.db.Transactiondb.addTransaction(Transactiondb.java:40)
at dataminer.svn.download.SVNLogManager.processTransaction(SVNLogManager.java:45)
at dataminer.svn.download.SVNLogManager.processSvnLog(SVNLogManager.java:26)
at dataminer.svn.download.SVNHistoryDownloadMgr.main(SVNHistoryDownloadMgr.java:160)
```

I have printed the prepared statement after binding. The printed query works fine when I run on command line. I saw this error in some other posts where the solution was to change my.cnf file for character encoding. I added these two lines to this file

```
character_set_server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_general_ci
```

It did not solve the error.

Comment: show the code written after `System.out.println("After binding " + stmt.toString());`

Comment: This is the code after system out                                              `stmt.executeUpdate();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();

            if (rs.next()) {

                transactionId = rs.getInt(1);
            }


        } catch (Exception exe) {
            exe.printStackTrace();

        }`

Comment: Have you tried terminating your query with ;? It also looks like you have an extra " " after values(...). These are just guesses.

Comment: This was my bad :-( I was passing query string to executeUpdate() method earlier. I changed stmt.executeUpdate(query) to stmt.executeUpdate(). This works now.